# Is it possible to calculate the route when source and destination having same junction using A* algorithm?

Tags: gps, astar

I am using A* Algorithm to calculate the shortest path. The route was calculated based on the junction. Shortest route was calculated when there was two or more junction in between source and destination, but the route was not calculated when source and destination having same junction or without having junction.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the expected behaviour. Consider that if there is no edge between the source node and destination node, what could the route (list of edges) possibly be?